# How to split a column of lists in Pandas for export in Excel?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe

How can I separate the the following data obtained from the numpy calculation into different column?

```py
import random

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


low = 0
high = 500
sample_size = 5


def get_numbers(low, high, sample_size):
    return random.sample(range(low, high), sample_size)


p_one = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype=int)
p_two = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype=int)
p_three = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype=int)
p_four = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype=int)
p_five = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype=int)

c_one = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype=int)
c_two = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype=int)
c_three = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype=int)
c_four = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype=int)
c_five = np.array(get_numbers(low, high, sample_size), dtype=int)

for idn in range(0, 10):  # ------------------n+1 for the last process step
    p = [p_one, p_two, p_three, p_four, p_five]
    c = [c_one, c_two, c_three, c_four, c_five]

df_final = pd.DataFrame(
    list(
        zip(
            p,
            c,
            "storage_workload",
            "storage_R1",
            "storage_R2",
            "storage_R3",
            "storage_R4",
            "storage_cycle_time",
            "storage_n",
            "storage_avg_opt_gap",
        )
    ),
    columns=[
        "Processing",
        "Cleaning",
        "workload",
        "R1",
        "R2",
        "R3",
        "R4",
        "Cycle time",
        "n",
        "Percentage Gap",
    ],
)
```

[image]

Expected result in Excel:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: How flexible is your requirement for a merged cell for each column header? There are a couple of ways you could tackle this.

Comment: the merged cell will depend on the number of sample size, which is set as a parameter (estimated from 10 to 1000). Do you mind sharing me any example of this, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided (example of what I get when I run your code):

```py
                  Processing                  Cleaning workload R1 R2 R3 R4  \
0    [4, 184, 330, 234, 473]  [213, 259, 360, 15, 457]        s  s  s  s  s   
1  [314, 176, 226, 304, 444]  [452, 15, 131, 141, 189]        t  t  t  t  t   
2  [313, 268, 291, 478, 285]  [14, 401, 367, 265, 187]        o  o  o  o  o   
3   [162, 31, 366, 330, 484]  [361, 140, 441, 50, 215]        r  r  r  r  r   
4   [235, 360, 473, 342, 43]   [69, 437, 496, 41, 269]        a  a  a  a  a   

  Cycle time  n Percentage Gap  
0          s  s              s  
1          t  t              t  
2          o  o              o  
3          r  r              r  
4          a  a              a
```

Here is one way to do it using Pandas [from_records](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) and [MultiIndex.from_product](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```py
results = pd.concat(
    [
        pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            df_final[col],
            columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
                [[col], range(0, len(df_final.loc[0, col]))]
            ),
        )
        for col in ("Processing", "Cleaning")
    ],
    axis=1,
)
```

```py
print(results)
# Output
  Processing                     Cleaning
           0    1    2    3    4        0    1    2    3    4
0          4  184  330  234  473      213  259  360   15  457
1        314  176  226  304  444      452   15  131  141  189
2        313  268  291  478  285       14  401  367  265  187
3        162   31  366  330  484      361  140  441   50  215
4        235  360  473  342   43       69  437  496   41  269
```